# stray '\222' in program

Tags: c, assembly

new to C but I am having the following error when I run this: stray '\222' in program

```
unsigned long *new_intel_stack(unsigned long *sp, lwpfun func, void *arg)
{
    unsigned long *ebp;  

    push(sp,arg); /* argument */
    push(sp,lwp_exit); /* for lwp return purposes */
    push(sp,func); /* function's return address */
    push(sp,0x1abcdef1); /* bogus "saved" base pointer */
    ebp=sp;   /* remember sp from this point for later */
    push(sp,0x6c6f7453); /* push initial eax, ebx, ecx, edx, esi and edi */
    push(sp,0x66206e65); 
    push(sp,0x206d6f72); 
    push(sp,0x746e6957);
    push(sp,0x32207265);
    push(sp,0x21363030);
    push(sp,ebp);  /* push initial edp */

    return sp;
}
```

Comment: So load the file in your hex editor and try to find that character. What do you want us to do?!

Comment: If you happen to be on *nix, the output of `cat -vte` on this file might make it easier to spot.

Comment: The next time you ask a question like this it might be advisable to ask something like what are some good ways to detect this problem. You might also indicate when the error occurs. You're getting a compile time error, right, not a run-time error? Also, please don't forget to accept one of the answers; you only have one now.

Comment: @Lucas: Why are you shouting at me? Google it.

Comment: WHAT IS A CAPS LOCK KEY?

Comment: If octal (the most common case): 222 (octal) = 146 (decimal) = 0x92 (hexadecimal).

Comment: This stray character doesn't appear to be anywhere in the provided source code.

Comment: If it is a single one (only *one* stray character error), not an UTF-8 sequence, it could the [CE/CP-1250](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250#Character_set) one corresponding to RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK. The single quote, as posted here, is the normal [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters) single quote (0x27).

Comment: Related: *[Compilation error: stray ‘\302’ in program, etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19198332)*. It is a canonical, but only for valid UTF-8 sequences (it is, like this one could be, typically introduced when copying from web sites, PDF files, chat messages (e.g. Skype Chat), etc.).

Answer (score 5):

The most common cause for this type of error is writing code in an environment such as Microsoft Word that autocorrects to add fancy quotes and fancy apostrophes, and then copy-pasting into a source file. Open your program in a hex editor such as [Frhed](http://frhed.sourceforge.net/en/) and look for any byte value not in the range 00-7F. You may also be reversing the inputs and outputs in your command line invoking the compiler.

Comment: Yes - \222 is 0x92 which is one of those damn 'smart-quotes' that Word munges things up with: `’`

Comment: People write code in Word??! O.o

Answer (score 3):

That error means you have a stray non-ASCII character somewhere in your source file.  What you've pasted here is fine.  You might need to use the 'show whitespace' option in your editor or look at the file in a hex editor to find the stray byte and delete it.

It could also be that you're doing something funny with your objects and the compiler thinks they're source files - what commands are you using to build your application?